# Google add #gref hash to url

Tags: hashcode

I have a content website. I search recipe or content in Google like this **"manti tarifi"** and when I click the link on Google. Google adding #gref hash..

What is the this `#gref` and how can I remove this hash from the url?

SS -> http://prntscr.com/k7vreq

Comment: How come its showing only on yemek.com and no other site

Comment: I really don't know :). I checked All of code and cant found in code. İts only added on Google click

Answer (score 0):

It is the GTM tag that measure how much time user spend on the website before he/she goes back to SERP(Search Engine Result Page), it stands for new history fragment that is created for users that came from SERP.